# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException while fetching a SOAP response

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm getting below error while fetching a response from SOAP service from a java client:

```
[javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.carefirst.com/Enterprise/DAC/AddressRetrievalSchema", local:"AddressInfoResponse"). Expected elements are (none)]
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:447)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:372)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:342)
```

But I was able to successfully connect to the service from Eclipse but when deployed the jar to my webshere server i am getting this error.

There are no service end, it was able to successfully send the below response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:AddressInfoOut xmlns:ns0="http://www.carefirst.com/Enterprise/DAC/DACStatusService">
    <Output>
        <ns1:AddressInfoResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.carefirst.com/Enterprise/DAC/AddressRetrievalSchema">
            <ns1:Success>true</ns1:Success>
            <ns1:docProp>
                <ns1:Property PropertyName="BTCH_ID">222EOB222</ns1:Property>
                <ns1:Property PropertyName="outbound address line1">103 North Washington Street</ns1:Property>
                <ns1:Property PropertyName="outbound address city">Suitland</ns1:Property>
                <ns1:Property PropertyName="mail forwarding address line1">103 N WASHINGTON ST</ns1:Property>
                <ns1:Property PropertyName="mail forwarding address city">BRYANS ROAD</ns1:Property>
                <ns1:Property PropertyName="fiserv status">mailed</ns1:Property>
            </ns1:docProp>
        </ns1:AddressInfoResponse>
    </Output>
</ns0:AddressInfoOut>
```

WSDL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created by TIBCO WSDL-->
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:ns2="http://www.carefirst.com/Enterprise/DAC/AddressRetrievalSchema" xmlns:ns1="http://carefirst.com/Enterprise/Operations/SoapFault" xmlns:tns="http://www.carefirst.com/Enterprise/DAC/DACStatusService" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns0="http://www.carefirst.com/Enterprise/DAC/StatusRetrievalSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" name="Untitled" targetNamespace="http://www.carefirst.com/Enterprise/DAC/DACStatusService">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns="http://www.carefirst.com/Enterprise/DAC/AddressRetrievalSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.carefirst.com/Enterprise/DAC/AddressRetrievalSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
            <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"/>
            <xs:element name="AddressInfoRequest">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element ref="ns2:header" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element ref="ns2:body"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="AddressInfoResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element ref="ns2:Success"/>
                        <xs:element ref="ns2:docProp"/>
                        <xs:element ref="ns2:Error" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="BatchID" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Error">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element ref="ns2:msgCode" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element ref="ns2:msg" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Success" type="xs:boolean"/>
            <xs:element name="TransactionID" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="body">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element ref="ns2:BatchID"/>
                        <xs:element ref="ns2:TransactionID"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="docProp">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Property" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:attribute name="PropertyName" type="xs:string"/>
                                    </xs:extension>
                                </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="header" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="msg" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="msgCode" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:schema>
        <xsd:schema xmlns="http://carefirst.com/Enterprise/Operations/SoapFault" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://carefirst.com/Enterprise/Operations/SoapFault" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
            <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"/>
            <xsd:element name="fault">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="faultType" minOccurs="0">
                            <xsd:complexType>
                                <xsd:sequence>
                                    <xsd:element name="SystemUnavailableFault" minOccurs="0">
                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                            <xsd:sequence>
                                                <xsd:element name="msg" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="msgCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                            </xsd:sequence>
                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                    </xsd:element>
                                    <xsd:element name="SourceSystemInvalid" minOccurs="0">
                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                            <xsd:sequence>
                                                <xsd:element name="msg" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="msgCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                            </xsd:sequence>
                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                    </xsd:element>
                                    <xsd:element name="DataNotFound" minOccurs="0">
                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                            <xsd:sequence>
                                                <xsd:element name="msg" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="msgCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                            </xsd:sequence>
                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                    </xsd:element>
                                    <xsd:element name="ApplicationException" minOccurs="0">
                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                            <xsd:sequence>
                                                <xsd:element name="msg" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="msgCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                            </xsd:sequence>
                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                    </xsd:element>
                                    <xsd:element name="SystemTimeOutException" minOccurs="0">
                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                            <xsd:sequence>
                                                <xsd:element name="msg" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="msgCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                            </xsd:sequence>
                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                    </xsd:element>
                                    <xsd:element name="PackageNotCompiled" minOccurs="0">
                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                            <xsd:sequence>
                                                <xsd:element name="msg" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="msgCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                            </xsd:sequence>
                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                    </xsd:element>
                                    <xsd:element name="AuthenticationException" minOccurs="0">
                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                            <xsd:sequence>
                                                <xsd:element name="msg" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="msgCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                            </xsd:sequence>
                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                    </xsd:element>
                                    <xsd:element name="InputDataInvalid" minOccurs="0">
                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                            <xsd:sequence>
                                                <xsd:element name="msg" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="msgCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                            </xsd:sequence>
                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                    </xsd:element>
                                    <xsd:element name="DefaultFault" minOccurs="0">
                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                            <xsd:sequence>
                                                <xsd:element name="faultCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="faultMsg" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                            </xsd:sequence>
                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                    </xsd:element>
                                </xsd:sequence>
                            </xsd:complexType>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:schema>
        <xs:schema xmlns="http://www.carefirst.com/Enterprise/DAC/StatusRetrievalSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.carefirst.com/Enterprise/DAC/StatusRetrievalSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
            <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"/>
            <xs:element name="BatchID" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="CDWBatchID" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Error">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element ref="ns0:msgCode" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element ref="ns0:msg" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="StatusRequest">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element ref="ns0:header" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element ref="ns0:body"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="StatusResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element ref="ns0:Success"/>
                        <xs:element ref="ns0:docProp"/>
                        <xs:element ref="ns0:Error" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Success" type="xs:boolean"/>
            <xs:element name="TransactionID" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="body">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element ref="ns0:BatchID" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element ref="ns0:CDWBatchID" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element ref="ns0:TransactionID" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="docProp">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Property" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:attribute name="PropertyName" type="xs:string"/>
                                    </xs:extension>
                                </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="header">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element ref="ns0:senderID" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element ref="ns0:senderApp" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element ref="ns0:msgID" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element ref="ns0:msgVersion" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="msg" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="msgCode" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="msgID" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="msgVersion" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="senderApp" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="senderID" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:schema>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">
            <attribute name="base" type="anyURI"/>
            <attribute name="id" type="ID"/>
            <attribute name="lang">
                <simpleType>
                    <union memberTypes="language">
                        <simpleType>
                            <restriction base="string">
                                <length value="0"/>
                            </restriction>
                        </simpleType>
                    </union>
                </simpleType>
            </attribute>
            <attribute name="space" default="preserve">
                <simpleType>
                    <restriction base="NCName">
                        <enumeration value="default"/>
                        <enumeration value="preserve"/>
                    </restriction>
                </simpleType>
            </attribute>
            <attributeGroup name="specialAttrs">
                <attribute ref="xml:base"/>
                <attribute ref="xml:id"/>
                <attribute ref="xml:lang"/>
                <attribute ref="xml:space" default="preserve"/>
            </attributeGroup>
        </schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:service name="DACStatusService">
        <wsdl:port name="StatusandAddressRetrievalPortEndpoint1" binding="tns:StatusandAddressRetrievalPortEndpoint1Binding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:9318/DACStatus_Services/BusinessProcesses/StatusandAddressRetrievalService/DACStatusService.serviceagent/StatusandAddressRetrievalPortEndpoint"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
    <wsdl:portType name="StatusandAddressRetrievalPort">
        <wsdl:operation name="StatusRetrieval">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:StatusIn"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:StatusOut"/>
            <wsdl:fault name="fault1" message="tns:Fault"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="AddressRetrieval">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:AddressInfoIn"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:AddressInfoOut"/>
            <wsdl:fault name="fault1" message="tns:Fault"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="StatusandAddressRetrievalPortEndpoint1Binding" type="tns:StatusandAddressRetrievalPort">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="StatusRetrieval">
            <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="/DACStatus_Services/BusinessProcesses/StatusandAddressRetrievalService/DACStatusService.serviceagent/StatusandAddressRetrievalPortEndpoint/StatusRetrieval"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" parts="Input"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" parts="Output"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="fault1">
                <soap:fault use="literal" name="fault1"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="AddressRetrieval">
            <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="/DACStatus_Services/BusinessProcesses/StatusandAddressRetrievalService/DACStatusService.serviceagent/StatusandAddressRetrievalPortEndpoint/AddressRetrieval"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" parts="Input"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" parts="Output"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="fault1">
                <soap:fault use="literal" name="fault1"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:message name="StatusIn">
        <wsdl:part name="Input" element="ns0:StatusRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="StatusOut">
        <wsdl:part name="Output" element="ns0:StatusResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="Fault">
        <wsdl:part name="Fault" element="ns1:fault"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="AddressInfoIn">
        <wsdl:part name="Input" element="ns2:AddressInfoRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="AddressInfoOut">
        <wsdl:part name="Output" element="ns2:AddressInfoResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Could anyone please help me this

Comment: I have used SOAP API (javax.xml.soap) instead of the classes generated from WSImport and it works fine with that.  Still don't know why it is failing in the first place though.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace of `AddressInfoResponse` in the shared response is according to WSDL but the unmarshaller is not expecting `AddressInfoResponse` element to be in namespace http://www.carefirst.com/Enterprise/DAC/AddressRetrievalSchema. 
It means the namespace is incorrect or empty in the java object against which the unmarshaller is trying to unmarshal. Please check the namespace against `AddressInfoResponse` object in your soap client. You need to check `package-info` class if you have auto generated the objects. In case you have created the client manually using SAAJ then you probably have missed the namespace for this element.

Comment: Yes these are auto generated using wsimport, package-info class seems to be fine:

Comment: It only fails when it is deployed part of a web application in Websphere , works fine when i run this standalone java

Comment: Looks like @XmlRootElement is missing on the root object. Please see http://www.source4code.info/2013/07/jaxb-marshal-unmarshal-with-missing.html